# GWT MouseOut event on a Composite

Tags: java, events, gwt

I have:

1. created a Composite,
2. initWidget-ed with an AbsolutePanel
3. added some Widgets to the Composite
4. in the Composite constructor attached a MouseOut handler

What I wanted to reach is detecting when the mouse is out of the Composite (or AbsolutePanel), but the MouseOut handler is fired whenever the mouse is out of *any* wideget in the AbsolutePanel.

Is there any clean way I can reach detecting the AbsolutePanel out?

The GWT I'm using is 2.0, with no add-ons (and I don't want to use any).

Comment: How about using `FocusPanel` instead of `AbsolutePanel`? Unless you have to position your `Widget`s absolutely, `FocusPanel` should give the same result plus it has all the nice Mouse/Keyboard interfaces implemented out of the box.

Comment: well, I *do* have to position the Widgets absolutely:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found a solution.

I extended the AbsolutePanel class, so that implements HasMouseoutHandlers. Now, instead of adding MouseHandler to the Composite, I add it to the MyAbsolutePanel only. This works fine.